# How to connection mongodb via ssh in nestjs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ssh, nestjs, tunnel

I have some problem.
I try connect mongodb via ssh but can not find solution..
I used 'tunnel-ssh' to connect from 'express' to 'mongodb' via 'ssh'.
But now we use 'nest JS'.
I would like to know how to connect to `mongodb` via 'ssh' using 'MongooseModule' provided by 'nestJS'.
Does anyone know how to connect 'mongodb' via 'ssh' in 'nestJS'

### My connectMongoDB func in express

```js
const connectMongoDB = () => {
  const config = {
    username: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    host: 'XX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
    port: 55963,
    dstPort: 27017,
  };
  const localMongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test';

  try {
    tunnel(config, (error /*, server */) => {
      if (error) {
        throw new Error(error as any);
      }
      connect(localMongoDB);

      connection.once('open', function () {
        connection.on(
          'error',
          console.error.bind(
            console,
            'Error: ',
          ),
        );
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

### tried it. (nestJS)

app.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test'),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Thank you everyone !

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async () => ({
        uri: <<uri>>,
        ssl:true
      })
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank u for ur answer
but My problem is connect mongodb via ssh. not use pem key.
I want connect to mongodb server using ssh, server hostname and server password.